# possessive genitive

Tags: genitive

I'm reading an article right now: https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/asien/iran-schauspielerin-alidoosti-verhaftung-101.html

where it says: Dieses Jahr feierte sie bei den Filmfestspielen in Cannes die Premiere ihren neuesten Film "Leila's Brothers".

But shouldn't it say ihres... Films instead? At least ihren should be ihres, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like an editing error, something was changed later without properly editing the case from accusative to genitive. It should be:

> ... die Premiere ihre**s** neuesten Film**s** "Leila's Brothers".

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The sentence is in the presented form grammatically wrong. It should probably read

> (...) Dieses Jahr feierte sie bei den Filmfestspielen in Cannes die Premiere ihres neuesten Films "Leila's Brothers". (...)

or

> Dieses Jahr feierte sie bei den Filmfestspielen in Cannes die Premiere von ihrem neuesten Film "Leila's Brothers".